# Bash script that should do stuff when the first command is CTRL+C-interrupted

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, interrupts

I want to make a bash script to automatize a simple task. This task involves running a `program` (not made by me) which do something until user presses CTRL+C. After that, I have to `process the output`. I have wrote this:

```
#!/bin/bash
program
process the output
```

`program` starts as expected, but when I press CTRL+C, `process the output` is not run. I bet my script just completely exits on CTRL+C.

How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a signal handler for SIGINT:

```
trap "echo Ctrl+C received" INT
program
trap - INT
process the output
```